# PowerShell - Dispose System.Net.CookieContainer?

Tags: powershell, system.net

Is there a way to dispose/close the CookieContainer?

```
$cc = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$cc = $null
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe

```
remove-variable cc
```

can do the trick.

edit:

```
$cc -is [idisposable]
```

return false!

Comment: @JNK - yes it could be the same.

Comment: oops, didn't see the comment.

Comment: @manojlds - no problems, yours answer are always a good thing!